How to handle custom error reporting in ScalaPB's GRPC wrapper
If I have a service's method throw an exception, my client receives no information about what kind of exception this was. I've read that this was made on purpose, to prevent server details being leaked to the client. However, I think it's still useful to give some information to the client, even if only for debugging purposes.
I've seen that io.grpc.Status may be what I'm looking for, but I'm unsure how to "return it" from a service's method, since it really doesn't fit the type signature of the method I'm returning, and it's also not throwable.
Is this usecase suported by scalapb's grpc wrapper? If so, what is the intended way of doing so?

Have you checked grpc error handling? That's the spec. Then it depends on the lib you used to implement the server or client. Scalapb has integration with many libs

Thanks for the first link! Actually, while I hadn't seen that specific link before, I did check out the grpc-java documentation on how it's used with io.grpc.Status. My problem is that this Status is sent through the onError method of a response observer, but simple non-streaming methods don't provide a responseObserver, so I'm unsure of how to interact with it.
The integration I'm using is the one provided by ScalaPB, which they themselves describe as a "thin wrapper around grpc-java". This is what I tried to convey in my last sentence.

You can throw a io.grpc.StatusException or io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException from your handler. These get a io.grpc.Status which will be sent to the client.
